# Como sobrepor uma imagem usando um texto que não seja clicável?

Tags: php, html, css

tudo bem? Bom, venho através desse tópico perguntar a vocês o seguinte:

Eu preciso criar uma maneira de sobrepor um texto em uma imagem, mas, eu quero que apenas a imagem seja um item clicável! Ou seja, eu quero que o texto sobreponha a imagem, mas, que ele (o texto) não fique selecionável.

Exemplo do que eu fiz:

[image: Exemplo]

Ao passa por cima do texto, o mesmo aparece como um texto clicável (pode selecionar, copiar, colar, clicar), sendo que, e eu quero apenas que ele apareça alí, sem ter nenhum tipo de interação.

CSS do **texto**:

```
.module .content .items .item .data {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 20px;
z-index: 20;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;}
```

CSS da **imagem**

```
.module .content .items .item .poster {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 140%;}
```

Agradeço demais quem puder me ajudar! ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para impedir qualquer tipo de interação com o mouse, você deve usar duas propriedades CSS:

- `user-select` como `none`, que irá impedir a seleção de texto;
- `pointer-events` como `none`, que irá impedir qualquer outra interação do mouse.

Então, basta adicionar:

```css
seletor {
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Ao elemento que deseja impedir as interações. :)

#### Referência:

- [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events);
- [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).

Comment: Certíssimo! Era exatamente oque eu estava procurando, muito obrigado, Luiz ♥

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar isto no `css` da tag que tenha o texto:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

```css
p {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Exemplo: você não consegue me selecionar!</p>
```

Obs: a imagem também não poderá ser selecionada e arrastada.